Increase the visibility of featured posts on Meta Stack Exchange
A comment on the recent Community Asks Sprint Notice (September 2024) by Dalmarus (Senior Community Manager), highlights a problem with the featured flag: there are too many darn things to feature!

There's limited space for featured posts (or more accurately, CMs around the world learned long ago that the more you pin/feature, the less that gets read, haha). At the time of this posting, there was a lot going on, so we made the call not to feature...

While I do understand that more things being featured does mean spreading the views thinner, I feel that some of the blame can fall on how there's no easy way to know if more than 3 questions are featured at any given moment. We've only really got the yellow "Featured" box, and that only shows off 3 posts at a time:

I propose that there should be a link to the featured tag page on the box when the number of featured posts exceeds the size of the box. Something like this:

On network sites, the text could be something like "View more on Meta Stack Exchange"

Another thing that could help, is to increase the amount of posts that can be featured, especially if there's no Overflow Blogs or other Yellow-box things going on (elections, community events, etc). It appears to be 3 at the moment. How about 5 total? I don't think this would be too detrimental or push down filters and tag favourite/ignores too far. Here's the Meta homepage at 720p with 5 featured posts.

On mobile, it takes up about half a screen.
What do you think?

In 2020, the team temporarily bumped the max featured Meta.SE posts on other sites by one.

@Sonic Oh lol. Temporary fixes are always the most permanent ones :D

It was later reverted, however.

The featured panel is full of uninteresting fluff (to avoid some bad words…). I don’t look at it anymore out of principle since it’s such a waste of time. Putting in even more drudgery won’t help the goal of getting people to look at the important stuff.

Featured Q&A should just be pinned in the question list…

@MisterMiyagi That's a shame - I use the box for featured posts only really. Couldn't care about the blog unless its truly horrendous and then I'm only reading it for the controversy. I like the idea to pin featured to the main page - feel free to raise that suggestion too. I'd add it here, but I feel like it's a bit further removed than this request, and it might do better on its own post
